# Multiple dynamic vertical lines on a chart with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to create multiple vertical lines on a single chart, these represent treatment dates. each line is to have a different value (date) and possibly different colour (depending on the treatment type) currently I have multiple lines but these are hard coded like below:

```
var Line = "25/03/2018";
var Line2 = "13/07/2018";

var treatments = [{
        type: 'line',
                  mode: 'vertical',
                  scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
                  value: Line,
                  borderColor: '#007e24',
                  borderWidth: 4,
                  label: {
                    enabled: true,
                    content: '13/07/2018'
                  }
      },
      {
        type: 'line',
                  mode: 'vertical',
                  scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
                  value: Line2,
                  borderColor: '#000',
                  borderWidth: 4,
                  label: {
                    enabled: true,
                    content: '13/07/2018'
                  }
      }

    ];
```

As data will be coming in from a CSV Is it possible to add something like below and create the number of treatments equalled to the number of items in the arrays and change the values and colours accordingly? So using below I would end up with 3 lines with the values and colours that are in the arrays?

```
var dates = ["01/03/2018", "01/05/2018", "09/10/2018"];
var colours= ["#000", "#000", "#fff"];

    var treatments = [{
            type: 'line',
                      mode: 'vertical',
                      scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
                      value: DYNAMIC VALUE,
                      borderColor: 'DYNAMIC VALUE',
                      borderWidth: 4,
                      label: {
                        enabled: true,
                        content: '13/07/2018'
                      }
          }

        ];
```

Or if there is any other workaround that may be possible to create this?

Thanks! Hope this makes sense!  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it right, you can loop through the dates array and build the treatments array with a for loop.

I've not run it, but the below should at least point you in the right direction - it assumes there are the same number of colours as dates.

```
var dates = ["01/03/2018", "01/05/2018", "09/10/2018"];
var colours = ["#000", "#000", "#fff"];
var treatments = [];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    treatments.push({
                  type: 'line',
                  mode: 'vertical',
                  scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
                  value: dates[i],
                  borderColor: colours[i],
                  borderWidth: 4,
                  label: {
                    enabled: true,
                    content: '13/07/2018'
                  }
      });
}
```